# database transaction isolation mode

Tags: mysql, pdo

i have a sequence table -- it holds the next sequence number for a variety of tables

with regards to database transactions that get rolled back:

- (1) sequence=3
- (2) process 1 sets sequence to 4
- (3) process 2 sets sequence to 5
- (4) process 1 rolls back (i would assume the sequence would be rolled back to 3)
- (5) process 2 commits (seeding its tables with a sequence of 5)

my question is this: will step (3) have to wait until process 1 commits or is rolled back?  is there a specific transaction isolation mode i should be thinking about?